# Archlinux Pacman Partial Upgrades - Finding Package Dependency Issues

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am working on an Archlinux system where we cannot use pacman -Syu to update our packages. I have very limited hardware and disk space and running pacman -Syu will add about 250MB of files to the disk, which is too much for the project.

Are there any packages or methods out there that to help me find missing dependencies?

Example: we upgraded a few packages then found out that sfdisk was broken because it was looking for libreadline.so.7 and we had libreadline.so.8, however pacman did not show any conflicts.

Comment: ArchLinux doesn't support partial upgrades https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported, maybe you shouldn't use ArchLinux considering your usecase.

Comment: You are going to have to research the packages to find their dependencies and then install them manually. As for `libreadline`, you can create a `libreadline.so.7` symlink pointing to `libreadline.so.8`

Comment: Usually library numbers are bumped when they are not backward compatible, so a symlink have chances not to fix the issue in my opinion.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET I know for a fact that a symlink of libreadline7 to libreadline8 works because I've used it for that specific package and many others across several distributions including Arch Linux. The number is moved up when new features are added. It doesn't mean that it isn't backwards compatible. The software probably just has that version of it hard coded in which is causing it not to look for anything else. There would be no way for the developer(s) to determine that it isn't backwards compatible with every piece of software that used the prior version.

Comment: I was wondering about the symlink fix. Good to know that it's an option.